# How to map number to marital status

Tags: c#

I have a marital status field in a database with numbers each representing a marital status in a different table. The first table has numbers 1, 3, 4:

```
1 = single 
3 = married
4 = divorced
```

The second has the values:

```
single
married
divorced
```

I need an if statement as follows: if the table field returns the value 1 I want to write the message 'single', if 3 'married' and if 4 'divorced' (using Response.Write).

Comment: (Attempted to clean up question, not sure if I didn't accidentally changed its meaning.)

Answer (score 6):

Rather than write an "if" statement in C#, why not just perform a join in the database to retrieve the text as part of the database query?

Comment: do you mean a stored procedure that retrieves the text value , if so i cant create one on that database because it is managed by another department and im not allowed to perform writes only read data from it

Comment: so i cant create any stored procedures on there

Comment: @Meg: No, I mean that you must already be doing a query to fetch the values - so change the SQL to perform a join against the description table as well.

Comment: Doing a join in your sql statement and make use of enums would be the best solution. And both usages are actualy meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 6):

You can write if else, or case statement, but easier to just use array for such a small list

```
string[] maritalStatus = new string[] { "", "Single", "", "Married", "Divorced"};

Response.Write (maritalStatus[dbValue]);
```

Comment: I like this, creative and flexible. +1

Comment: I would suggest that a Dictionary<int, string> might be more appropriate than an array of strings, with the elements added as such "maritalStatus.Add(1, "single") etc.

Comment: Thanks for the votes. Agree Dictionary works well but just a few more lines to write. With a short list, the above is just short and concise and would have looked better if the id didnt actually jump

Comment: Hmm. I never hardcode strings in my code that come from the database. What if the values do change? Multilanguage etc.?

Comment: Agree. If it is for multilingual environment, the string will have to either come from DB or from resource file. If I put the string in the resource file, I can string use the above array but replace the hardcoded text in quote with a resource property.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to declare an enum that maps to your values like this:

```
enum RelationshipStatus
{
    Single = 1,
    Married = 3,
    Divorced = 4
}
```

Then you can just call the ToString method of the variable containing your enum value. Note that you'll need to cast the integer value from your SQL table to the enum type.

The advantage of this approach is that you can eliminate the conditional if statement entirely and I think the result is much more readable. The disadvantage is that it won't be easy to localize to other languages (translations) if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
string GetStatus(int StatusCode)
{
    return StatusCode == 1 ? "single" : StatusCode == 3 ? "married" : "divorced";
}
```

BTW there is usually no good reason to normalize this far. Performance would be better if you stored the actual status in the table and the amount of disk space is negligible.

**Edit:** @jon's idea is probably better than this function

Comment: So, 10 million records... Storing 1, 3, 4 = 10MB data (1 byte per entry for tinyint). Storing name = 140MB (avg 7 chars, 2 bytes per char).  It's not huge, but it's not exactly negligible.

Comment: Compared to the performance of all the joins or the function calls to resolve the number to a string I think 130mb in this day and age can be considered negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an Enum would be the most elegant approach?

```
public enum MaritalStatus
{
    Single = 1,
    Married = 3,
    Divorced = 4
}
```

Then you can simply use Enum.GetName() and Enum.Parse() to convert between string, int and MaritalStatus objects. This may also provide you with a more elegant solution in some of your other business logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of different ways to do that, good and bad ways

1. If you can join the tables in query - there's one good way
2. You could use SQL-CASE in procs
3. You could switch-case/if in middle tier/C# code.
4. You could create enums and type cast

like 
`

```
public enum MaritalStatus
    {
        Single = 1,
        Married = 3,
        Divorced = 4
    }

MaritalStatus status = (MaritalStatus) 4;
Console.WriteLine(status);
```

`
and so on